# Identify latest added or updated files in Windows file folders

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management, disk-utility

In Windows Explorer, I would like to list all the files in a folder, including those in subfolders, and sort them by the time they were added, or the last time they were modified.

I am trying to figure out the last time my file(s) were deployed to any one of those subfolders.

Comment: Latest what time? Last updated? That might not match the time the files were added to the folders. Last accessed has been disabled by default since Vista I believe.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Windows 8 Explorer view ribbon, showing sort options]

It is possible to list all of the files in a folder (including those in subfolders), by typing an asterisk (`*`) in the search bar.

From there you can click the `Sort by` button in the `View` ribbon panel, and click `Date Modified` and `Descending`.

Alternatively, if you are viewing the results as `Details` (a view setting you can change in the `View` ribbon, as shown in my screenshot), you can just click the `Date Modified` column title.

If instead, you want to sort by `Date Created` or any other criteria, if you click `Sort By > Choose Columns`, you can sort by a wide range of criteria (as shown below).

[image: Windows 8 Choose Details window]